# cURL empty request data if https connection

Tags: php, linux, shell, curl

I try to send the file via POST. Before that i used http connection and everything worked. But now `var_dump($_REQUEST);` in my php-file returns an empty array.

This my curl log:

> $ curl -X POST -F "id=1" -F "file=@/tmp/file.txt" https://MY_DOMAIN/save_file.php
>   -v
>
> - Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
> - Trying MY_IP...
> - Connected to MY_DOMAIN (MY_IP) port 443 (#0)
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: none CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
> - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: C=RU; OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=MY_DOMAIN
> - start date: 2015-12-30 14:29:37 GMT
> - expire date: 2016-12-30 14:29:37 GMT
> - subjectAltName: MY_DOMAIN matched
> - issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
> - SSL certificate verify ok.
>
>   > POST /save_file.php HTTP/1.1
>   >     User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
>   >     Host: MY_DOMAIN
>   >     Accept: */*
>   >     Content-Length: 95611662
>   >     Expect: 100-continue
>   >     Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------4cf633b06b612b7d
>   >      < HTTP/1.1 100 Continue < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> - Server nginx/1.10.1 is not blacklisted < Server: nginx/1.10.1 < Date: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 22:22:53 GMT < Content-Type: text/html;
>     charset=utf-8 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked < Connection: keep-alive <
>     Set-Cookie: mwc=f25mv8leksepc8qg1t7de0rdk5; path=/ < Expires: Thu, 19
>     Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT < Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>     must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 < Pragma: no-cache <
>     Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; <  array(0) { }
> - Connection #0 to host MY_DOMAIN left intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in an unexpected place: the file size exceeds the allowable load